# Reducing the text view container size in css

Tags: css

I am stuck with this simple thing. Basically, i want to make something like this:
[image: Username]

but my username view covers the whole width of the page and i get something like this:
[image: my view]

My css style:

```
h3{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #675eaf;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}
```

Comment: use width: 60%;
that should work

Comment: you can use text-align: center; to align the text.
if the whole view is shifting to left, you can use position:absolute and then left: 40%; or whatever puts it in the center

Comment: Ok thank you. i set the margin to auto. seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i set the max-width to about 20% and added margin:auto and it works.